# Opencart 3.0.2.0, Email sending failed while Using Gmail

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, opencart-3

My Opencart version is 3.0.2.0

My problem is that email is not working recently. I am using gmail smtp and it was working few days before. But suddenly it stopped working and while checking error log I found below log.

*PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Error: Password not accepted from server!' in /home/MYFOLDERNAME/public_html/system/library/mail/smtp.php:206*

I am using Linux hosting.

And below is my mail configuration

**Mail Engine** : SMTP, 
**SMTP Hostname** : tls://smtp.gmail.com, 
**SMTP Username** : mygmailid@gmail.com, 
**SMTP Password** : mygmailpassword, 
**SMTP Port** : 587

I have enabled less secure apps in https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1 and also 'Account access enabled' in https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha.

My gmail account is active and I can login in web.

Also I tested the same with below details, but still it is not working.

**SMTP Hostname** : ssl://smtp.gmail.com & **SMTP Port**: 465

Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, just to ask, do you solved it? because from 30 may 2022 google no longer support the use of less secure apps.... so I'm wondering if you find another way, I have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Extra settings needed to be set if you're using G Suite, especially use it as your domain mail

1. go to https://admin.google.com and login
2. select "Security" on your console panel
3. select "Basic Settings"
4. "Less secure apps", "Go to settings for less secure apps"
   https://admin.google.com/AdminHome?fral=1#ServiceSettings/notab=1&service=securitysetting&subtab=lesssecureappsaccess
5. Choose the 3rd one :)
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFxUw.png
   Disable access to less secure apps for all users
   Allow users to manage their access to less secure apps
   **Enforce access to less secure apps for all users**

Hope this can help